# Keying node removing everything but the green screen

Tags: compositing-nodes, movie-clip-editor, chromakey

I'm just learning how to green screen. I started in Movie Clip Editor, opened a clip, added a Mask, and then switched to the Compositing tab, and added the nodes shown in the pictures.

This was all according to a tutorial. And in the tutorial the green screen disappeared. However, for me only the green screen remains. Not sure what I'm doing wrong?

[image: Inverted green screen]

Comment: Purple does not qualify as "green" screen... call it "color key" or "chroma key"...

Comment: I readded the nodes in a different order and it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I readded the nodes in a different order and it worked.

I don't remember what order made it not work. But to make it work I added nodes in this order:

1. Movie Clip
2. Keying (and set the Key color)
3. Connect 1 to 2
4. Mask
5. Color Invert
6. Connect 3 to 4 to 5

(Note that both setups are the same as in the image in the question, only the order of adding was different)

Comment: I could not get this to work.  The Mask node has no input, so how can 3 connect to 4?

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the "Color invert node"

Comment: The color invert node just inverts the mask, so that the area I'm interested in gets selected rather than the background

Comment: To tackle that, connect the "Matte" in the "Keying Node" to "Alpha" in the "Viewer node"

Comment: Hmm, that didn't have any effect. In any case, I readded the nodes in a different order, and now it's working. Thank you for your time and effort

Comment: Alright. Since the problem has been solved, please mark it as Solved

Answer (score 0):

This node setup works (just ignore the brightness & gamma nodes shown here).  I used "color key" node", but it's the same principle for the "keying node".

- The original image goes int the "key" node
- The "key" matte goes into the "color ramp" node

  - Note the the ramp is inverted with white on the left.  That inverts the key to show only the selected color.
- The "color ramp" goes into the factor of the "alpha over" node

  - The original image goes into the bottom slot of "alpha over"
  - The background images goes into the top image slot of "alpha over".  In the example, I left the top slot empty.

[image]